# Traveling to Ecuador with a layover in Panama. Do I need Yellow Fever vaccine?

Tags: legal, health, panama, ecuador

I will be traveling to Quito, Ecuador in a few weeks. I'm flying on Copa Airlines from the United States with a 3 hour layover in Panama (PTY). I will also fly back from Quito to the United States via Panama.

I just found out [from the CDC](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/ecuador) and other sources that if you come from a country with Yellow Fever, you need proof of vaccination. Quoting from the website:

> The government of Ecuador requires proof of yellow fever vaccination if you are traveling from a country with risk of yellow fever (this does not include the US - for complete list, see Countries with risk of yellow fever virus transmission).

My question is easy: do I need the vaccine because of short layover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just called Copa Airlines, my carrier. They said that I don't need this vaccine.

So the general answer to this question seems to be "Call your airline"

Edit:

One month later, this was indeed the case. Went USA-> Panama -> Ecuador -> Panama -> USA with no problem.

Comment: Hello. I will be doing same trip this December and going to canal tour when coming back (layover of 10 hours). I don't need vaccination, do I? Thanks

Comment: @JuanCa I think you have enough time to get the vaccination. Go for it!

Comment: @JuanCa It also depends what part of Equador you will visit.

Comment: Thanks, it is better to get vaccinated (I will). I am only going to Quito, and maybe (maybe) Manabi